# Storing large NSData in Core Data. Is core data "smart" enough to evoke un-neaded fetch data when there is a memory warning?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a `NSMangedObject` custom class similar to:

```
@interface MyManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * creationDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * imageData;

@end
```

I want to store large `UIImages` (transformed to `NSData` outside of the `NSManagedObject`) - The relevant `view controller` is responsible for inserting to the DB objects with `imageData` using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`....

Issue is that these managed objects drive a `collection view` of hundreds if not thousands of cells -

The flow as of now:

```
@implementation ViewController

-(void)insertNewManagedObjectWithImageDataAndUpdateView:(NSData *)data {
   MyManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([MyManagedObject class])
inManagedObjectContext:sharedContext];

newManagedObject.imageData = data;
... // add more stuff to the object as needed

// add to internal datasource
[self.myData addObject:newManagedObject];

//update the view
self.collectionView performBatchUpdates^{
  [self.collectionView insertCellsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:newItemIndex inSection:0]];
} completion:(BOOL success) {
}];
}

// UICollectionview datasource

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SomeCustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageData = self.myData[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
@end

@implementation SomeCustomCell

-(void)setImageData:(NSData *)imageData {
  [self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
@end
```

From what I understand , the "`imageData`" property in the `managed object` is auto-saved to the DB context, but it is always kept in memory (as long as it was set during creation or fetched at some point by the "`SomeCustomCell`" instance)

How can I "`nilify`" the `imageData` in memory to conserve it but ensure it is kept in the database? What is the correct way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Core Data itself does not observe memory warnings. It's up to your application to trim the in-memory object graph appropriately in response to memory warnings.

Calling `-[NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject:mergeChanges:]` with the appropriate arguments will flush the in-memory object and any un-faulted properties out of memory. Unsaved changes will be lost.
Calling `-[NSManagedObjectContext reset]` will flush *all* in-memory objects from that context. Again, unsaved changes will be lost.

In a collection view or table view it's common to call `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` on model objects as their cells go off screen.

This is covered in the Core Data Programming Guide sections [Faulting and Uniquing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html) as well as [Reducing Memory Overhead](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW4)